# Js remove element from array without change the original

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if there is a way to do this without make a full copy of the array and then splice the copy.

```
var arr = [{id:1, name:'name'},{id:2, name:'name'},{id:3, name:'name'}];
```

I need to temp remove element by his index and use the array without this element, but i dont want to change the original array.

You can give me way even with lodash.

Comment: check the 'slice' method :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` will create and return a new array consisting of elements that match the predicate.

```
function removeByIndex(array, index) {
  return array.filter(function (el, i) {
    return index !== i;
  });
}
```

Even shorter with ECMAScript 6:

```
var removeByIndex = (array, index) => array.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
```

Comment: Thats not changed the original?

Comment: @anguLaravel, no, it won't mutate the original array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [es6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and `Array.prototype.splice`

```
var arr = [{id:1, name:'name'},{id:2, name:'name'},{id:3, name:'name'}];

let newArr = [...arr]
newArr.splice(index)
```

The spread operator copies the array and splice [changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: You should call out that .splice() returns the REMOVED elements, as opposed to the new array without the item at that index.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) seems a better choice to me to remove an array element **without mutation**:

```js
let fruits = ['peach', 'pear', 'apple', 'plum'];
let result = [...fruits.slice(0, 2), ...fruits.slice(3)];

console.log(fruits); // ['peach', 'pear', 'apple', 'plum']
console.log(result); // ['peach', 'pear', 'plum']
```

[Source](https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-array-element-without-mutating/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{id:1, name:'name'},{id:2, name:'name'},{id:3, name:'name'}];
var index = 1;
var result = Array.prototype.concat(arr.slice(0, index), arr.slice(index + 1, arr.length));
```

It merges left and right part of the array, the delimiter here is the element you want to delete.

Comment: You could also spread here, instead of using concat.
`var result = [...arr.slice(1)]`